# pulling from a specific data from a row and column in a database

Tags: php, sql, database

My data base looks like this.
its ordered ascending by NO#
And col2 is the start of the database NO# is basically invisible and only used as a reference as to row number
so lets say I wanted to display on a web page the text in col8, row 5. What would the php code be?

PS. the connect code is seperate and not an issue hence i did not include itI

```
-|NO#|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10
---------------------------------------------------
 |1  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |2  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |3  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |4  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |5  |    |    |    |    |    |    |2012|    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |6  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |7  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |8  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |9  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
 |10 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my code but it whites out the page when I try to load it.

```
<?php 
//selects row
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Inventory` WHERE NO# = '5'";
//select column
$col8 = $row['col8'];
// fetch the results
WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($query):
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// display the results
<div id="year">echo "$col8";</div>
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: What does it mean 'whites out the page'?

Comment: If you're just selecting one column from one row, you don't need a while loop - you can just assign `$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);` directly (Also, there looks like a missing bracket in the WHILE statement)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: @emil-It does not display the text 2012 like I want it too.@ethrbunny-Have you ever clicked don a page and all you seen was a white page no text no pics just white.@andrew im not trying to display a whole column or whole row. Im trying to display the text 2012 in a div.

Comment: @null- You want me to try to do it in a new code when I cant even get help with old code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something like what's below. I have not tested this code, though.

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT `col8` FROM `Inventory` WHERE `NO#` = '5' LIMIT 1" );
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
?>
<div id="year"><?php echo $row['col8']; ?></div>
```

Hopefully that'll help you out a bit.

Comment: I edited the select statement to encompass NO# in backticks. I think the pound sign may be causing the issue. Also, the white screen typically means you have a syntax error and error reporting is disabled. Otherwise the error would show.